# The BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(plainPassword) not return the same value after each times submit and re-submit

Tags: spring-security

I appy the Spring security in my application and use BCrypt for encode password and I got sometime can login and sometime not logined.I used the code to generate hash password like below:

System.out.println(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("admin"));

And I got many result not the same after re-submit.This is some result print out:

-$2a$10$xbM.XFChI0fV2RYqPe/XSewxSRSzwcbJ5TFAFGACRkTaHWmxL1x..

-$2a$10$VOaha9xUUfzHL0hpd5.HE.RaLx5Gldy/MjapBoQUYYTGVdHLcSh8q

-$2a$10$1/Kf/Un2oQzARrD.SHsh2OC/Dxwpj1aIeatydMEQSbxgfxOkDF27e==

-$2a$10$o61u5t/r0R2jhOouDGWCFuwOLl31NIh8UiDVzRN4TSBybUs4keCmW

That reason sometime I can login and sometime not.

Please help to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct; `BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode()` should always return a different result. That's a security measure which makes it harder to crack the encoded password (this is called "[salting passwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)")

If you want to know whether a password is correct, you need to use [BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html#matches%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.